# Using like operator to filter columns names in scala

Tags: python, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe, out of which I want to create a list of all those columns that starts with some phrase and ends with some other phrase.

Please help me write the statement, currently I am using startswith and endswith , which works separately correct , but with AND condition it doesn't work.

Kindly help me write SCALA code.

Below is the line I want to execuete

```
  val list_inactive_w  = usg.columns.filter(_.startsWith("max_consecut") AND (_.endsWith("ays_data_w")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val list_inactive_w  = usg.columns.filter(s=>s.startsWith("max_consecut") && s.endsWith("ays_data_w"))
```

Comment: Thanks - This worked , Please let me know what does this S do in this statement?

Comment: "S" is just a parameter like _ , in this case you can use _ only once and "s" multiple times, this "s" is just a name, can be different

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

I have written a code in python and took all the columns of a dataframe which has type string in python, Now I want to do the same in scala .

I am new to scala , Can you please help. Below is the code.

val cons_Day3= [t[0] for t in df2 if t[1] == 'string']

Comment: you can check types this way:
`df.schema.foreach(x=>print(x.dataType))`